# JPA - using annotations in a model

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

My application runs on JPA/Hibernate, Spring and Wicket. I'm trying to convert our ORM from XML files to JPA annotations. The annotated model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
public class User extends BaseObject {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return Returns firstName and lastName
     */
    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    }
}
```

Originally, though, it was without annotation and the mapping was described in User.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.appfuse.model.User" table="app_user">
        <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="first_name" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="lastName" column="last_name" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="email" column="email"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I delete the mapping file and try to use just the annotations, the entityManagerFactory doesn't get created, with the exception

> `org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   Could not find a setter for property
>   fullName in class
>   org.appfuse.model.User.`

There's no mapping set for this property, because it's just a convenience method. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mark the method as  [`@Transient`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) so Hibernate will ignore it:

```
/**
 * @return Returns firstName and lastName
 */
@Transient
public String getFullName() {
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}
```

By default, everything that looks like a getter is mapped.

Comment: Would it also ignore it if the method itself was transient (public transient String getFullName)

Comment: @Jamie: The `transient` keyword works only on member variables, not on methods, so that's not an option.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake. If a field was transient, and had public getters & setters, would it still be necessary to mark it with the @Transient annotation?

Comment: ofcourse, JPA only looks at the @Transient annotation, not at the transient keyword. marking the variable as transient has no effect for JPA

Comment: @Jamie That also works. @Salandur: No, marking a member variable as `transient` keeps it from being persisted just as well. The hiberante docs say: "Every non static non transient property (field or method depending on the access type) of an entity is considered persistent, unless you annotate it as `@Transient`." http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property