# Documentation - How do I declare a method transient in hibernate hbm.xml file?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbmxml

I want to declare a method transient in a hibernate entity, and we are using hbm.xml files for the mappings instead of annotations.

I see sparse mentions online of people declaring fields transient in xml, declaring method transient with annotations, but I cannot find the documentation for declaring methods transient in xml. I see some mentions that if it's not in the hbm.xml file Hibernate will ignore it, but I'd like to confirm.

Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659594/can-properties-mapped-in-hbm-xml-be-transient

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one, but I'm not sure how the `transient` keyword applies to methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy XML mapping documentation seems to be removed since Hibernate 5.But you can still find its documentation in the [Hibernate 4 documentation, section 5](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration).

And it is true when using `hbm.xml` , if you don't need to map a field or a method , just do not include it in `hbm.xml`. I cannot find this behavior is mentioned explicitly in the documentation as I think it is a common sense for people to think it back to the time when there is only legacy XML mapping.

And after introducing annotation mapping , it introduced the features that the mapping fields will be auto-detected by default which does not require to explicitly declare all mapping fields . The differences of this behaviour between legacy XML and annotation mapping are somehow mentioned in the documentation implicitly as follows:

> You need to decide which property needs to be made persistent in a
>   given entity. This differs slightly between the annotation driven
>   metadata and the hbm.xml files.
>
> In the annotations world, every non static non transient property
>   (field or method depending on the access type) of an entity is
>   considered persistent, unless you annotate it as @Transient. Not
>   having an annotation for your property is equivalent to the
>   appropriate @Basic annotation.